# @OneToMany returning null for List<> field

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

It seems that I run into an issue with regards to how I am modelling a particular problem with Spring entities.
So I have `orders` , `product` and `product_line` as three separate entities.
An order can have multiple `product_lines`. For context, a `product_line` essentially is of the form `id, product_id, quantity`.
Now I want a situation where, when I retrieve an order from the database, it should pull all `product_lines` associated with the order.
When I try to retrieve an order , the products field is always `null`. The way I see it is, because an `Order` can have multiple `ProductLines`, I use the `List<ProductLine>` on the `Order` but seems to not work.

```
@Table(name = "orders")
public class Order{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<ProductLine> products;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    private User user_id;
}

public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
}

public class ProductLine {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne
    private Product product;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int quantity;
    @JoinColumn(name="order_id")
    @ManyToOne
    private Order order;
}
```

For extra clarity, this is how I am saving orders (some lines have been ommitted):

```
Order orderToBeSaved = Order.builder().user_id(existingUser.get())
                .build();
        Order savedOrder = orderRepository.save(orderToBeSaved);
        List<ProductLine> productLines = new ArrayList<>();
            ProductLine productLine = ProductLine.builder()
                    .product(product)
                    .quantity(value)
                    .order(savedOrder)
                    .build();
            productLines.add(productLine);
        });
        productLineRepository.saveAll(productLines);
//Just for verification purposes
//x is null for some reason
        var x = orderRepository.findOrderById(savedOrder.getId()).get().getProducts();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by Hibernate's first level cache. Hibernate tries to look for the entity in the cache first, if it is not found then it is loaded from the database.

Initially the newly created order has the list of `ProductLine` as null. Doing the save operation puts the object into hibernate's cache, still with the null list of `ProductLine`.

When `findOrderById` is called, hibernate finds the entity `Order` in the cache and returns it.

This reference check can be done to prove the above.

```
// both objects are pointing to the same memory location
if(savedOrder == orderRepository.findOrderById(savedOrder.getId()).get()){
    log.info("Same order object!")
}
```

Unfortunately to overcome the first level cache, the `EntityManager` needs to be autowired to the class.

Firstly perform a `EntityManager#flush` which will save all the entities into the database followed by `EntityManager#clear` which clears the hibernate's first level cache hence forcing the next queries to fetch data from the database.

```
Order savedOrder = orderRepository.save(orderToBeSaved);
List<ProductLine> productLines = new ArrayList<>();
    ProductLine productLine = ProductLine.builder()
            .product(product)
            .quantity(value)
            .order(savedOrder)
            .build();
    productLines.add(productLine);
});
productLineRepository.saveAll(productLines);

entityManager.flush();
entityManager.clear();

orderRepository.findOrderById(savedOrder.getId()).get().getProducts();
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the fact that you are using a bi-directional relationship, I think you might be missing to add the ProductLine object(s) into the products List from Order. Something like this

```
    Order orderToBeSaved = Order.builder()
                .user_id(existingUser.get())
                .build();
        
    Order savedOrder = orderRepository.save(orderToBeSaved);

    List<ProductLine> productLines = new ArrayList<>();
            ProductLine productLine = ProductLine.builder()
                    .product(product)
                    .quantity(value)
                    .order(savedOrder)
                    .build();
            productLines.add(productLine);
        });
        //this
        productLines.forEach(
            (ProductLineEntity) ->{
                savedOrder.getProducts.add(ProductLineEntity) 
        });
        orderRepository.save(savedOrder);
        productLineRepository.saveAll(productLines);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are explicitly querying for product lines like order.getProducts() a FetchType.LAZY will defer the fetch for your Order object. Try FetchType.EAGER to see if that works or just call order.getProducts() and see if that triggers the fetch.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But that is what I am doing actually. Kindly check the edited version of my post.

Comment: Because it seems like you are saving and fetching in the same transaction you could try a orderRepository.saveAndFlush() after the orderRepository.save() and before the orderRepository.findOrdersById() and see if that helps. I'm not entirely sure if the lazy fetch pulls from cache or is expecting that value to be persisted to the actual table.

Comment: Good point, tried it but all to no avail. I will investigate a bit more.